# Struts 2 s:submit button syntax to set values in map

Tags: java, struts2

I am browsing some Struts 2 code and I see this syntax for submit button that I haven't seen before..

```
<s:submit key="map.keyName$Value" />
```

It's not working (it was working with Struts 2.0.x now we have moved to Struts 2.2.3) any more. I mean its not setting the appropriate value based on the mentioned key in the map.

Has anyone used this syntax before?

Any other alternative syntax suggestions that will let me SET values in a map (using struts tag only) will be most welcome.

The jsp page containing this code is designed to be a decoupled component that can be included by any page at runtime that's why this page CANNOT call any java code to set these values in java map - which is why i am looking for tag solution that can set values in the map.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set value in a map by :

**In JSP only**

**OGNL** assignment statement :

```
<s:set var="" value="map[key] = keyValue" />
```

**Java**

```
<s:set var="" value="map.put(key, keyValue)" />
```

---

**EDIT**

You could set value in map (to action class) with

```
<s:hidden name="map[key]" value="keyValue" />
```

by submit button with **onclick** attribute, for example (**answer** - assume multiple submit button) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setMap(key, keyValue) {
        document.getElementById("mapToSet").name="map['" + key + "']";
        document.getElementById("mapToSet").value=keyValue;
    }
</script>

<s:hidden name="test" id="mapToSet" />
<s:submit value="Search" onclick="setMap(key, keyValue)" />
```

Comment: I need to set this value in map when the s:submit button is clicked. Can s:set tag be nested inside s:submit tag ?

Comment: thanks lschin, your solution does the job. But my problem is I cannot base such critical functionality of our application on javascript because the client requires the application to work correctly even when the end user has the javascript disabled. So I am still looking for some struts/jstl tag based solution that will do this setter job for me without calling an action.

Answer (score 2):

I found this page when searching for "how to set values in a map in Struts2" and it led me to the following answer (which I understand is a little OT):

---

As an HTML input element:

```
<input type="hidden" name="myField[105]" value="myValue" />
```

This would populate an action variable declared as:

```
Map<Integer, String> myField;
```

such that:

```
myField.get(105).equals("myValue"); // == true
```